NET MAUI CollectionView iOS Application Scroll Performance Degrades After Initial Smoothness
I'm developing an iOS application using .NET MAUI and encountering a performance issue with a CollectionView. When the application first opens, scrolling works perfectly smooth. However, after scrolling a few times (approximately 10 scroll up and down actions), the scrolling begins to slow down and stutter noticeably.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Could you please add some relevant code to help us reproduce the issue?

I have a CollectionView with 50 items, using a grid layout with 2 columns. There are no other scroll views outside the CollectionView; it uses its own scrolling mechanism. Scrolling to the bottom is smooth, and scrolling back up is also smooth. However, after several cycles of scrolling to the bottom and back to the top, the performance gradually degrades, causing the application to become unusable due to stuttering. I am unable to reproduce this issue today, but I plan to do so in the coming days. @LiqunShen-MSFT

Upon investigation, I discovered that the problem was related to the use of the IconTintColorBehavior property from the Community Toolkit. This behavior was applied to set tint colors for icons based on the display names of items using a converter. While this approach worked efficiently on Android devices, it resulted in significant performance issues on iOS devices, causing scrolling to become sluggish and jittery.
After removing the IconTintColorBehavior, the scrolling performance on iOS devices improved drastically, and the issue was resolved.

Alpay Çalışır
Maybe you miss the topic Can I answer my own question? from the help center

Glad you solved it! You may customize the behavior based on the platform using OnPlatform markup, refer to Customize UI appearance based on the platform
